# background-image binding in Ionic 3 not working, no matter how I pass it

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, binding

I'm having a very weird problem with `Ionic 3` (template binding I thing, specifically with styles) which has had me blocked these last days, without being able to find a solution or even knowing what can be causing this. I hope anybody can help me to troubleshoot and fix whatever is going on.

I'm working on an application in `Ionic 3`. In one of its pages, there is a list containing some text and images as background-images. There is where my problem appears. Images are not showing, and I can't find a way to make them work, although I have tried all the possible solutions I have read all over the internet.

Images are in the local `assets` folder. The path to the image comes from an array of objects which has an 'image' property, containing the path `(assets/imgs...).` I am sure the path is correct because if I use  with `[src]="coto.image" (single element and his property, generated by an *ngFor)` the image is displayed. For background-image binding I have tried using:

```
[style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + coto.image + ')'"
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + coto.image + ')'}"
style="background-image: url({{coto.image}})"
```

Note: absolute external URLs ARE working. For example:

```
[style.backgroundImage]="'url(https://example.com/image.jpg)'"
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(https://example.com/image.jpg)'}"
style="background-image: url(https://example.com/image.jpg)"
```

BUT if I set a variable = "https://example.com/image.jpg" and bind it to the template, the same way I do with coto.image ([ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(imageVar)'}", it doesn't work too.

Another thing I have noticed is that if I set the route of the local image manually, (assets/imgs...; the same that should be passed by the coto.image item from the *ngFor), it is still not working, which seems the most weird for me.

Also tried the bypassSecurityTrustStyle from DOMSanitizer, with any results...

```html
<div class="image" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + coto.image + ')', 'min-height': '180px'}">
<!-- <div class="image" [style.minHeight.px]='180' [style.backgroundImage]='"url(" + coto.image + ")"'> -->
<!-- <div class="image" style="background-image: url({{ coto.image }})"> -->
<!-- <img [src]="coto.image"> -->
</div>
```

If anyone has any knowledge on what's going on here I would be very grateful to read it, because the more I try to solve this more lost I feel I am.

Thank you very much!

*P.S: sorry for any grammar or spelling error I have made, English is not my mother tongue =)

Answer (score 0):

Well, after an interesting amount of time, the light turned on. The problem was related to the name of the images ("image (1).jpg", "image (2).jpg"...). I removed the "()" and now it works perfectly. The problem seems to be related with some sanitizing that Ionic applies to HTML/styles/whatever in templates, which probably doesn't allow "()". It's strange because in Angular it does works... I hope this helps anybody who may have had the same problem.